# Alertdialg with custom adapter containg checkbox and its listener

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, custom-adapter, android-checkbox

I am using `custom adpater in AlertDialog`. In that adapter, i am using `TextView and CheckBox`.. 
Now I want to handle CheckBox's `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for checking checked or unchecked CheckBox.. And according to status of CheckBox, I want to implement some code. But this listener is fired more than one time.. So how can I handle it? Suggest me if anyone has an idea.

And exactly my problem is when i checked on checkbox, i want to increment some value and when i unchecked, i want to decrement some value.but i am not getting exact sum value and if i scroll then this sum value is changed.. so what i have to do?

Following is my Custom Adaper :

```
private class Updateinfo_ServiceAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _options_services.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Viewholder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_updateinfo_service, null);
            holder=new Viewholder();
            holder.txtname=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.serviceName);
            holder.chkSelected=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(Viewholder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtname.setText(_options_services[position]);        
        holder.chkSelected.setChecked(_selections_services[position]);



        holder.chkSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
            {

                if (isChecked) {
                    allowServicesSum = allowServicesSum
                            + Integer.parseInt((String) services[position]
                                    .getSystemServiceID());
                    System.out.println("AllowService sum is "+allowServicesSum);
                } else {
                    allowServicesSum = allowServicesSum
                            - Integer.parseInt((String) services[position]
                                    .getSystemServiceID());
                    System.out.println("AllowService sum is "+allowServicesSum);
                }
            }
        });

               if(_selections_services[position])
        {
            holder.chkSelected.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.chkSelected.setEnabled(true);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private class Viewholder
    {
        TextView txtname;
        CheckBox chkSelected;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten that in the case where you reuse the existing `convertView`, the listener is already set. Thus, when you do `holder.chkSelected.setChecked`, that will trigger the listener that was set the previous time you returned this view from `getView`.

The easiest way to avoid the problem is to call `holder.chkSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);` immediately after the line `holder=(Viewholder)convertView.getTag();`. This makes sure there is no listener when you later call `setChecked`, after which you can add the listener again.

Comment: i called listener immediately after gettag.. but not works.. my problem is when i checked on checkbox, i want to increment some value and when i unchecked, i want to decrement some value. but if i scroll then this sum value is changed.. so what i have to do?

Comment: I updated my answer to make it clear that you have to **unset** the listener. Sorry that wasn't clear initially.

Comment: if i unset the listener then still there is problem..if i checked the item and scroll down then that selected item will be unchecked automatically. so what should be done here ?

Comment: That's because you're setting the checkbox's state from `_selections_services[position]`, but you don't update that array when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Comment: Ya you are right.. now i put that _selections_services[position] true or false according to checkbox staus.so now it works fine..Thanks a lot.but now concern is  that by default i checked some items and i want this items disabled.. so how can i achieve ? please see my updated question for disabling checkbox..

Comment: I've answered your question now. You can't just keep changing it to add more things until we've written your whole app for you.